# How to encode this character in python

Tags: python, character-encoding, twitter

I got this (ÜT:) character result from location in twitter using twitter-api.

i dont know how to encode this character to  remove it from the result.

example of the string ==> `"ÜT: -7.0651362,110.4596271"`

already try with `"&#220;T:"` to check the string but it no effect

```
if "&#220;T:" in t.location: print "yes, it contain the char"
```

how to remove the character in python.

thanks before.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: already get the answer using the unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',string_to_convert).encode('ascii','ignore')

Answer (score 0):

I have never dealt with the Twitter API but doesn't its documentation say which encoding strings are returned in by default?

If this `"ÜT:"` character always appears at the beginning of a string, you can also get rid of it by splitting the string at the first whitespace character:

```
>>> s = "ÜT: -7.0651362,110.4596271"
>>> s.split(" ", 1)[1]
"-7.0651362,110.4596271"
```